# How to convert protobuf enum into String for Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, protocol-buffers

We can create a Protobuf enum as below

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.example.androidprotogenerator.data";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message ModeOption {

  enum Mode {
    NONE = 0;
    ECSTATIC = 1;
    HAPPY = 2;
    SAD = 3;
    DEPRESSED = 4;
  }

  Mode mode = 1;
}
```

When used in Android (Java and Kotlin), I can easily get the enum type as String

```
ModeOption.Mode.values()
    .filterNot { it == ModeOption.Mode.UNRECOGNIZED }
    .forEach { print(it.name) }
```

How can I do it for Swift Proto Enum?

I can get all the cases out using

```
ModeOption.Mode.allCases
```

But I have no way of printing the string of the enum.

**Update**

The generated swift code as below, where one can see the enum string in `SwiftProtobuf._NameMap`

```
// DO NOT EDIT.
// swift-format-ignore-file
//
// Generated by the Swift generator plugin for the protocol buffer compiler.
// Source: mode_options.proto
//
// For information on using the generated types, please see the documentation:
//   https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/

import Foundation
import SwiftProtobuf

// If the compiler emits an error on this type, it is because this file
// was generated by a version of the `protoc` Swift plug-in that is
// incompatible with the version of SwiftProtobuf to which you are linking.
// Please ensure that you are building against the same version of the API
// that was used to generate this file.
fileprivate struct _GeneratedWithProtocGenSwiftVersion: SwiftProtobuf.ProtobufAPIVersionCheck {
  struct _2: SwiftProtobuf.ProtobufAPIVersion_2 {}
  typealias Version = _2
}

struct ModeOption {
  // SwiftProtobuf.Message conformance is added in an extension below. See the
  // `Message` and `Message+*Additions` files in the SwiftProtobuf library for
  // methods supported on all messages.

  var mode: ModeOption.Mode = .none

  var unknownFields = SwiftProtobuf.UnknownStorage()

  enum Mode: SwiftProtobuf.Enum {
    typealias RawValue = Int
    case none // = 0
    case ecstatic // = 1
    case happy // = 2
    case sad // = 3
    case depressed // = 4
    case UNRECOGNIZED(Int)

    init() {
      self = .none
    }

    init?(rawValue: Int) {
      switch rawValue {
      case 0: self = .none
      case 1: self = .ecstatic
      case 2: self = .happy
      case 3: self = .sad
      case 4: self = .depressed
      default: self = .UNRECOGNIZED(rawValue)
      }
    }

    var rawValue: Int {
      switch self {
      case .none: return 0
      case .ecstatic: return 1
      case .happy: return 2
      case .sad: return 3
      case .depressed: return 4
      case .UNRECOGNIZED(let i): return i
      }
    }

  }

  init() {}
}

#if swift(>=4.2)

extension ModeOption.Mode: CaseIterable {
  // The compiler won't synthesize support with the UNRECOGNIZED case.
  static var allCases: [ModeOption.Mode] = [
    .none,
    .ecstatic,
    .happy,
    .sad,
    .depressed,
  ]
}

#endif  // swift(>=4.2)

#if swift(>=5.5) && canImport(_Concurrency)
extension ModeOption: @unchecked Sendable {}
extension ModeOption.Mode: @unchecked Sendable {}
#endif  // swift(>=5.5) && canImport(_Concurrency)

// MARK: - Code below here is support for the SwiftProtobuf runtime.

extension ModeOption: SwiftProtobuf.Message, SwiftProtobuf._MessageImplementationBase, SwiftProtobuf._ProtoNameProviding {
  static let protoMessageName: String = "ModeOption"
  static let _protobuf_nameMap: SwiftProtobuf._NameMap = [
    1: .same(proto: "mode"),
  ]

  mutating func decodeMessage<D: SwiftProtobuf.Decoder>(decoder: inout D) throws {
    while let fieldNumber = try decoder.nextFieldNumber() {
      // The use of inline closures is to circumvent an issue where the compiler
      // allocates stack space for every case branch when no optimizations are
      // enabled. https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1034
      switch fieldNumber {
      case 1: try { try decoder.decodeSingularEnumField(value: &self.mode) }()
      default: break
      }
    }
  }

  func traverse<V: SwiftProtobuf.Visitor>(visitor: inout V) throws {
    if self.mode != .none {
      try visitor.visitSingularEnumField(value: self.mode, fieldNumber: 1)
    }
    try unknownFields.traverse(visitor: &visitor)
  }

  static func ==(lhs: ModeOption, rhs: ModeOption) -> Bool {
    if lhs.mode != rhs.mode {return false}
    if lhs.unknownFields != rhs.unknownFields {return false}
    return true
  }
}

extension ModeOption.Mode: SwiftProtobuf._ProtoNameProviding {
  static let _protobuf_nameMap: SwiftProtobuf._NameMap = [
    0: .same(proto: "NONE"),
    1: .same(proto: "ECSTATIC"),
    2: .same(proto: "HAPPY"),
    3: .same(proto: "SAD"),
    4: .same(proto: "DEPRESSED"),
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Where is your Swift code? Swift enumerations (RawRepresentable) has a rawValue property if that is what you are asking. If your enumeration rawValue is Int type you would need to provide that custom name instance property

Comment: I have added the Swift code generated for your reference @LeoDabus

Comment: Technically, it isn't supported as per https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/1111. We'll just have to make do with some of the recommendations below I suppose e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71552207/3286489

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you make it conform to CustomStringConvertible you can simply print your cases or convert/initialize a new string from any case

Comment: Normally Protobuf Model is shared commonly by all, hence after it's generated, the iOS/Android/Server doesn't need to add extra code to support it. Assuming if someone add another mode, e.g. "MOODY", to the proto file, after one generate the Swift code, in our case, we'll need to manually add the `CustomStringConvertible` ourselves. Ideally, we should get it from the generated Swift Proto code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to make `ModeOption.Mode` conform to `CustomStringConvertible`:

---

```
extension ModeOption.Mode: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let description: String
        switch self {
        case .none: description = "NONE"
        case .ecstatic: description = "ECSTATIC"
        case .happy: description = "HAPPY"
        case .sad: description = "SAD"
        case .depressed: description = "DEPRESSED"
        case .UNRECOGNIZED: description = "UNRECOGNIZED"
        }
        return description
    }
}
```

---

```
ModeOption.Mode.allCases   // [NONE, ECSTATIC, HAPPY, SAD, DEPRESSED]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
String(describing: myEnumRawValue)
```

So printing all strings:

```
for enum in ModeOption.Mode.allCases {
  print(String(describing: enum))
}
```

Should output:

```
none
ecstatic
happy
sad
depressed
```